# CiviMail "View in Browser" Link Error

Tags: civimail, error, tokens

I am on civi 5.14.2 drupal 7.x flexmailer & mosaico 2.x installed. It used to be working so far and all of a sudden it stopped working!! This email was sent using "traditional" link. Any idea what could go wrong? Here is the message I receive..

```
 Sorry, due to an error, we are unable to fulfill your request at the moment. You may want to contact your administrator or service provider with more details about what action you were performing when this occurred.
```

`Expected one Contact but found 0`

EDIT:getting debug message in drupal

> $Fatal Error Details = array(3) { ["message"]=> string(32) "Expected one Contact but found 0" ["code"]=> NULL ["exception"]=> object(CiviCRM_API3_Exception)#221 (8) { ["extraParams":"CiviCRM_API3_Exception":private]=> array(3) { ["is_error"]=> int(1) ["error_message"]=> string(32) "Expected one Contact but found 0" ["error_code"]=> string(9) "undefined" } ["message":protected]=> string(32) "Expected one Contact but found 0" ["string":"Exception":private]=> string(0) "" ["code":protected]=> int(0) ["file":protected]=> string(68) "/home/webadmin/public_html/cmm/sites/all/modules/civicrm/api/api.php" ["line":protected]=> int(45) ["trace":"Exception":private]=> array(7) { [0]=> array(4) { ["file"]=> string(82) "/home/webadmin/public_html/cmm/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Mailing/Page/View.php" ["line"]=> int(145) ["function"]=> string(12) "civicrm_api3" ["args"]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(7) "Mailing" [1]=> string(7) "preview" [2]=> array(3) { ["id"]=> string(3) "477" ["contact_id"]=> int(0) ["version"]=> int(3) } } } [1]=> array(6) { ["file"]=> string(76) "/home/webadmin/public_html/cmm/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php" ["line"]=> int(311) ["function"]=> string(3) "run" ["class"]=> string(21) "CRM_Mailing_Page_View" ["type"]=> string(2) "->" ["args"]=> array(2) { [0]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(7) "civicrm" [1]=> string(7) "mailing" [2]=> string(4) "view" } [1]=> NULL } } [2]=> array(6) { ["file"]=> string(76) "/home/webadmin/public_html/cmm/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php" ["line"]=> int(85) ["function"]=> string(7) "runItem" ["class"]=> string(15) "CRM_Core_Invoke" ["type"]=> string(2) "::" ["args"]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(15) { ["id"]=> string(3) "376" ["domain_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["path"]=> string(20) "civicrm/mailing/view" ["title"]=> string(12) "View Mailing" ["access_callback"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(19) "CRM_Core_Permission" [1]=> string(9) "checkMenu" } ["access_arguments"]=> array(2) { [0]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(28) "view public CiviMail content" [1]=> string(15) "access CiviMail" [2]=> string(16) "approve mailings" } [1]=> string(2) "or" } ["page_callback"]=> string(21) "CRM_Mailing_Page_View" ["breadcrumb"]=> array(2) { [0]=> array(2) { ["title"]=> string(7) "CiviCRM" ["url"]=> string(16) "/civicrm?reset=1" } [1]=> array(2) { ["title"]=> string(8) "CiviMail" ["url"]=> string(24) "/civicrm/mailing?reset=1" } } ["component_id"]=> string(1) "4" ["is_public"]=> string(1) "1" ["is_ssl"]=> string(1) "0" ["weight"]=> string(3) "800" ["type"]=> string(1) "1" ["page_type"]=> string(1) "0" ["page_arguments"]=> bool(false) } } } [3]=> array(6) { ["file"]=> string(76) "/home/webadmin/public_html/cmm/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php" ["line"]=> int(52) ["function"]=> string(7) "_invoke" ["class"]=> string(15) "CRM_Core_Invoke" ["type"]=> string(2) "::" ["args"]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(7) "civicrm" [1]=> string(7) "mailing" [2]=> string(4) "view" } } } [4]=> array(6) { ["file"]=> string(78) "/home/webadmin/public_html/cmm/sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/civicrm.module" ["line"]=> int(444) ["function"]=> string(6) "invoke" ["class"]=> string(15) "CRM_Core_Invoke" ["type"]=> string(2) "::" ["args"]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(7) "civicrm" [1]=> string(7) "mailing" [2]=> string(4) "view" } } } [5]=> array(4) { ["file"]=> string(48) "/home/webadmin/public_html/cmm/includes/menu.inc" ["line"]=> int(527) ["function"]=> string(14) "civicrm_invoke" ["args"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(7) "mailing" [1]=> string(4) "view" } } [6]=> array(4) { ["file"]=> string(40) "/home/webadmin/public_html/cmm/index.php" ["line"]=> int(21) ["function"]=> string(27) "menu_execute_active_handler" ["args"]=> array(0) { } } } ["previous":"Exception":private]=> NULL } }
>
> $backTrace = #0 /home/webadmin/public_html/cmm/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(463): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE) #1 /home/webadmin/public_html/cmm/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(55): CRM_Core_Error::handleUnhandledException(Object(CiviCRM_API3_Exception)) #2 /home/webadmin/public_html/cmm/sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/civicrm.module(444): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:3)) #3 /home/webadmin/public_html/cmm/includes/menu.inc(527): civicrm_invoke("mailing", "view") #4 /home/webadmin/public_html/cmm/index.php(21): menu_execute_active_handler() #5 {main}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try updating the version of flexmailer extension to latest from https://github.com/civicrm/org.civicrm.flexmailer?

I think this problem was resolved via https://github.com/civicrm/org.civicrm.flexmailer/pull/33 and related PRs.

Comment: Thanks. I think the issue was with combination of flexmailer & tradition settings. Once I have changed the mailhandler to flexmailer it started working.